# Error when communicating with the native messaging host with java application and chrome extension

Tags: java, user-interface, google-chrome-extension

i built java application that get data from chrome extension and return data.
the chrome extension work perfect when my java app without this line:

```
scanner = Scanner.getDevice();
```

in this code:

```
    ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
    scanner = Scanner.getDevice();
    scanner.addListener(this);
```

but when i not delete the line i got error on my background.js:

```
Error when communicating with the native messaging host
```

how can i debug the problem ?
the Scanner its:

```
uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner
```

library

tnx a lot.

Comment: This could happen if communication was interrupted or invalid data was sent. Maybe that scanner software tries to write something into the stdout pipe?

Comment: maybe... but how can i check it? its jar library that i downloaded from the interent to scan a document, i tried to run the app with the line and without and the same outputs i saw in the cmd.